# How to vertically align divs of varying heights?

Tags: css

i have the following set up

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="box1" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box4" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box5" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box6" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box5" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box1" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box4" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box6" class="list"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="list"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #000000;}
.list{display: inline-block;margin: 0px 10px;}

#box1{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#FF0000; width: 121px; height:36px;}
#box2{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#00FF00; width: 125px; height:39px;}
#box3{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#0000FF; width: 185px; height:52px;}
#box4{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#FFFF00; width: 183px; height:26px;}
#box5{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#FF00FF; width: 105px; height:44px;}
#box6{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#00FFFF; width: 170px; height:34px;}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubs4y5a/)

each `<div class="list">` actually would hold a single image but for the purpose of this i set the widths and heights to be that of the divs high if the images were there. and yes i am away of the duplicate ids but in reality these divs wont have ids, just the class.

anyway i am trying to get these divs to vertically align for each line. the vertical align needs to be dynamic to the point that if the tallest box (ie. `#box3`) is removed from a line (because of the re-sizing window moved it to a different line or it was removed all together from HTML) the line should adjust accordingly (ge. if `#box3` and `#box5` were on the same line where other lines almost touch `#box3` border, when all `#box3` is removed the other lines should now almost touch `#box5` border)

As you can see i am already using vertical align with no avail. so what other CSS do i need?

Comment: You should not have duplicate IDs in your document. You can assign multiple classes to an element: `class="list box1"`.

Comment: @roeland *"and yes i am away of the duplicate ids but in reality these divs wont have ids, just the class."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `vertical-align` to the elements themselves instead of the wrapper.

**CSS**

```
#wrap{margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000000; }
.list{display: inline-block;margin: 0px 10px; vertical-align: middle;}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nbwc3690/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox to achieve the desired result if you are okay with current browser support for flexbox.

Using flexbox provides the ability to evently distribute your images horizontally in each row and align them at their vertical centers.

```css
/* Flex container */
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
/* Each div inside container */
.container div{
  align-self: center;
  margin:20px;
}

#box1{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#FF0000; width: 121px; height:36px;}
#box2{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#00FF00; width: 125px; height:39px;}
#box3{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#0000FF; width: 185px; height:52px;}
#box4{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#FFFF00; width: 183px; height:26px;}
#box5{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#FF00FF; width: 105px; height:44px;}
#box6{border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#00FFFF; width: 170px; height:34px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box3"></div>
  <div id="box4"></div>
  <div id="box5"></div>
  <div id="box6"></div>
  <div id="box5"></div>
  <div id="box3"></div>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box4"></div>
  <div id="box6"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrap{
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.list{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0px 10px;
   vartical-align: middle;
}
```

please try to vartical-align middle in .list class....

is this work?